# HTML5 data being read as a number instead of a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<tr id="row_1" data-rk="02000008" data-pk="0001I">
```

When I check this with firebug it shows as:

```
dataset DOMStringMap { rk="02000008", pk="0001I"}   
pk "0001I"  
rk "02000008"
```

I then use jQuery to read this:

```
var pk = $("tr[id='row_" + row + "']").data('pk')
var rk = $("tr[id='row_" + row + "']").data('rk')
```

However this is what the firebug debuggers shows when I check the values in my javascript. They are also the same values that are later sent to my C# code in an Ajax call.

```
pk shows as "0001I"
rk shows as 2000008
```

Can someone explain this? Both rk and pk are coded in the same way, both have one or more leading zeros but the one returns as a string and the other as a number.

Comment: HTML don't present fixed var types. So jQuery "guess" what it is regarding the content.

Comment: Try `alert(typeof rk)` to see if it really is a number. Attributes should always be strings, if jQuery is changing it to a number then that is a bad thing to do. From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5): "Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null) otherwise it is left as a string." So it is by design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript autoparses so the trailing 'I' in `"0001I"` causes javascript to interpret it as a string

Comment: Thanks. The other answers were correct also but your point about the trailing I is very good and explains.

Comment: It is not javascript that is converting it to a number, that is jQuery trying to second guess the developer.

Answer (score 4):

This is [by design](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5):

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null) otherwise it is left as a string. To retrieve the value's attribute as a string without any attempt to convert it, use the [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method.

What you have to use instead is:

```
var pk = $("tr[id='row_" + row + "']").attr('data-pk')
var rk = $("tr[id='row_" + row + "']").attr('data-rk')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var pk = $("tr[id='row_" + row + "']").attr('data-pk');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since jQuery is messing up your data, you can do:

```
var rk = document.getElementById('row_' + row]).getAttribute('data-rk');
```

and you are guaranteed a string.